# Sending message from Kafka to socket.io in python

Tags: python, socket.io, apache-kafka

I have an end-to-end pipeline of an web application like below in `Python3.6`

```
Socket(connection from client to server) -> Flask Server -> Kafka Producer ->Kafka Consumer ->NLPService
```

Now when I get some `result` back from the `NLPService`, I need to send it back to the client. I am thinking below steps

1. NLP service writes the `result` to a different topic on Kafka producer (done)
2. Kafka consumer retrieves the `result` from Kafka broker (done)
3. Kafka consumer needs to write the `result` to the flask server
4. Then flask server will send the `result` back to the socket
5. Socket writes to client

I have already done steps 1-2. But stuck at step 3, 4. How do I write from Kafka to the flask server? If I just call a function at my server.py, then logically it seems like I have to create a socket within at function at server.py which will do the job of sending to client through socket. But syntax wise it looks weird. What am I missing?

at `consumer.py`

```
#receiving reply
topicReply = 'Reply'
consumerReply = KafkaConsumer(topicReply, value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('ascii')))
for message in consumerReply:
    #send reply back to Server
    fromConsumer(message.value)
```

at `server.py`

```
socketio = SocketIO(app)

def fromConsumer(msg):
    @socketio.on('reply')
    def replyMessage(msg):
        send(msg)
```

The above construct in `server.py` doesn't make sense to me. Please suggest.